# Android Studio update 0.5.8 to 0.5.9: Gradle sync failed

Tags: android-studio

Today, after updating my Android Studio from 0.5.8 to 0.5.9, I received error "Gradle project sync failed...", and many errors. As I can see, Studio can't load libraries, it highlights me importing:

import android.support.v4.app.**FragmentActivity**;

import com.google.android.gms.**maps**.GoogleMap;

Bold text is red in Studio.
I also notice, that 3 files are deleted after updating:

```
.idea\libraries\appcompat_v7_19_1_0.xml
.idea\libraries\play_services_4_2_42.xml
.idea\libraries\support_v4_19_1_0.xml
```

Thus, `.idea\libraries\` now is empty!

Comment: After reverting this files back, they remove themself o_O probably by Studio...

Comment: Does this help? https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=70490

Comment: Unfortunately, this problem have many people.

Comment: I think it's better to downgrade to 0.5.8

Comment: Is there a way to downgrade without downloading whole 0.5.8 version?

Comment: No you'll need to reinstall. I haven't heard a root cause of this problem yet so I'm not sure what a workaround would be if you don't want to downgrade.

Answer (score 0):

For "Gradle project sync failed..." error follow these steps:
1- change classpath to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.11.+'`

2- Download the "Android SDK Build Tools 19.1"

3- Change your buildToolsVersion to `buildToolsVersion '19.1'`

4- Rebuild your project

That´s all. I solved the same problem that you have a few minutes ago following these steps.

I'm not sure how to solve the other problems you have but could be related to the actualizations that you have if you open the SDK Manager.

I hope this helps somebody!